# Difficulty Dynamically Inserting CheckBoxes at Correct Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I want to create dynamic CheckBox I have problems inserting them at the correct position. I want to place them below the input field, and not below the Image. I don't' really now how to place them in this way I described.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KAALv/11/)

HTML:

```
 <div id="modalDialog">
    <form>
        <p>Description:</p>
        <input type="text" id="customTextBox" style="width: 100%; font-size: 120%;" />
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <p>Card due Date:</p>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width: 15%" />
        <input type="button" id="Getbtn" value="Get value" />
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <p>Things To Do:</p>
        <div id="progressbar">
            <div id="progress">
                <div id="pbaranim"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Create CheckBox:</p>
        <input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSaveCheckBox" value="_Ok" />
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <p>
            <img src="/Pages/Images/comment.png" width="40" height="40" style="display: inline-block" />Comments:</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: 0,
            max: 100
        });

    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
    var container = $('#modalDialog');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;

    $('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 'cb' + id,
        value: name
    }).appendTo(container);
    $('<label />', {
        'for': 'cb' + id,
        text: name
    }).appendTo(container);
    $('<br/>').appendTo(container);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your code is appending the checkboxes to the `modalDialog` element, which is the container for all the items you see, as such they are added after everything else.

Simply add a new element (e.g. called `checkboxes`), place it where you want the checkboxes to appear, and append the checkboxes to this, a la:

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KAALv/12/)

HTML

```
<div id="modalDialog">
    <form>
        <p>Description:</p>
        <input type="text" id="customTextBox" style="width: 100%; font-size: 120%;" />
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <p>Card due Date:</p>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width: 15%" />
        <input type="button" id="Getbtn" value="Get value" />
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <p>Things To Do:</p>
        <div id="progressbar">
            <div id="progress">
                <div id="pbaranim"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Create CheckBox:</p>
        <input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSaveCheckBox" value="_Ok" />
        <div id='checkboxes'></div>
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <p>
            <img src="/Pages/Images/comment.png" width="40" height="40" style="display: inline-block" />Comments:</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: 0,
            max: 100
        });

    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
    var container = $('#checkboxes');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;

    $('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 'cb' + id,
        value: name
    }).appendTo(container);
    $('<label />', {
        'for': 'cb' + id,
        text: name
    }).appendTo(container);
    $('<br/>').appendTo(container);
}
```